# Graphing nr of threads in WPA

Tags: etw, xperf, windows-performance-analyzer

I want to graph the number of threads in a process, have found the
ThreadID coloumn and set the Unique Count aggregation which is what I want to see over time. I have this field alone to the right of the blue bar, but no graph is shown (yes I have selected the legend colour).

How is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the Thread ID column name, and choose **Open View Editor**. 
In the opened window, scroll the list down until you see the **Thread ID** entry. Under the **Aggregation** column, select **Count**.

Now it should display a graph of the amount of threads.

Notice that you should correctly set the first column in the left-most part of the table, to either **Process**, or **Thread Start Module**, according to your need.